# Prevent SqlPackage from writing to primary partition during Export

Tags: sql-server, azure, sqlpackage, bacpac

To move a 144GB SQL Server database to Azure SQL I want to export it to the .bacpac format.

To do so I use SQL Package of SQL Version 130:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin>SqlPackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:MY_MSSQL_INSTANCE /sdn:MY_DATABASE /tf:d:\export.bacpac /p:Storage=file
```

However, this fails because my primary partition (C:, with 39GB free) runs out of disk space during the operation. As you can see in the command I try to export to D:. It seems the export script does something temporary on C:.

How can I prevent that? (I already checked the default SQL Server Temp path, it's also on D:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it again on a VM having 300GB and even 600GB of free disk space, it still fails to work. I will now go to try other methods: Microsoft Data Migration Assistant, or transfer schema first and then use SQL Server Import Export Wizard to move the data.

Answer (score 1):

SqlPackage.exe uses three locations on disk: the selected output path, the temp folder, and the [isolated storage folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage#isolated_storage_locations).

By default the temp folder and the isolated storage folder are on the primary drive. I believe you can change temp folder location by changing the environment variable and then (in the same command prompt) running SqlPackage.exe, like so:

```
set TMP=d:\temp
SqlPackage.exe /a:export ...
```

This may not be sufficient, though, because of the use of Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

With version 18.7 there is a new parameter available for that `/p:TempDirectoryForTableData=(STRING)`

Answer (score -1):

Increase the C drive size and execute.